# Generating a PGP keypair with passphrase in Golang

Tags: go, encryption, gpgpu, pgp, key-pair

I am trying to generate a PGP keypair (public and private keys) and passphrase in Golang. I have found a few different functions for generating keys but nothing to generate the keypair with the passphrase. I've been using Gopenpgp but am open to using any library. If someone could give me an example of generating a PGP keypair with a passphrase it would be much appreciated. This is what I currently have (although I know this won't work because the private key and public key aren't even generated together):

```
    passphrase = "passphrase"
    privateKey, err = helper.GenerateKey("name", "email", []byte(passphrase), "rsa", 4096)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", "", nil, nil, err
    }
    publicKey, err = helper.GenerateKey("name", "email", nil, "rsa", 4096)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", "", nil, nil, err
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `go.mod` require: `github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2 v2.4.10`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/crypto"
    "github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/helper"
)

func main() {
    var (
        name       = "Max Mustermann"
        email      = "max.mustermann@example.com"
        passphrase = []byte("LongSecret")
        rsaBits    = 2048 * 2
    )

    // RSA, string
    rsaKey, err := helper.GenerateKey(name, email, passphrase, "rsa", rsaBits)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(rsaKey)

    keyRing, err := crypto.NewKeyFromArmoredReader(strings.NewReader(rsaKey))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    publicKey, err := keyRing.GetArmoredPublicKey()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(publicKey)
}
```